# How to run a asp.net MVC4 web application in RedHat OS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, redhat

I have created an MVC4 web application using visual studio. I published/hosted that website in IIS. It works fine in IIS. I want to run this same web site in RedHat. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the Mono article on [running ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC on Mono on Linux](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).